# plot a 3D matrix of concentrations in matlab with slice

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix C=51x51x11 dimensions, obtained from a function in a separate script, the x,y,z represent length, depth and height, and the value represent a concentration per x,y,z point. I want to create a slice crossing x and another crossing y showing the difference in concentration by color. I have tried using ngrid and meshgrid but didn't work. may i have some help with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [slice()](http://cog.brown.edu/research/badrelab/papers/Badre_Frank_Moore_Neuron_2015)

```
C = randi(1,[51,51,11]);
x= 25; y = 25; z = 5;
sl = slice(C,x,y,z);
```

[image: sliced]

Comment: When i do this im getting the figure but all the slices have the same color so i cant see the difference in concentration im looking for

Comment: Sounds like your matrix may not have been assigned correctly. Can you confirm that each point in C is not the same value?

Comment: All values are different but they are really small numbers like 0.005 or stuff like that, it could be related to this magnitude?

Comment: Ok in that case  change your colorscale to reflect your range `caxis([min_val, max_val])`

Comment: Also you probably have an outlier that  is washing out your scale. If that's the case try using 2 standard deviations as scale `caxis([mean(C(:))-2*std(C(:)), mean(C(:))+2*std(C(:))]);`   (the threshold you select should be chosen based on what you see in your data but 2 SDs is a good place to start)

Comment: That works thank you. Im also trying to create a surface plot with this data but im getting confused. I want a x vs y vs C plot but i cant call the variables in the surf function. You have any advice?

Comment: No problem. Not entirely sure what you mean by that, it really depends what your data looks like. A good starting place is here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/overview-of-volume-visualization.html.

Comment: Do you mean looking at the x-y plane? To do that you can use `imagesc(C(:,:,z_cut))` to look at the x-y plane color at each section `z_cut` ;  `imagesc(mean(C,3))` to look at the x-y plane collapsed across the z-dimension as a mean, or whatever else you'd like as long as you collapse across the z dimension. It gets tricky when you also want to visualize z. Depending on your data you may want to do a sparse scatter3 plot, an isosurface rendering, or even use a movie/gif to represent the z-coordinate as time.

Answer (score 1):

Using slice inside a function to make it easy to view in 3d:

```
function eslice(V,sx,sy,sz)
    slice(V,sx,sy,sz)
    shading interp
    axis equal
    axis vis3d
end
```

[image]

This is from my personal library, enjoy.